# C pointer type cast

Tags: c

```
float fNum = 12.3;
int *pF = (int *)&fNum;
printf("fNum:%f pF:%d \n", fNum, *pF);
*pF = 233;
printf("fNum:%f pF:%d \n", fNum, *pF);

return 0;
```

The result is like this

```
fNum:12.300000 pF:1095027917 
fNum:0.000000 pF:233
```

I want to know why the result like this? Don't `fNum` & `*pf` point to the same memory?

Comment: Should be more specific about what result is bothering you and why? What did you expect it to be in the first place.

Comment: `0.000000` is the correct decimal representation to display with 6 significant digits, and it appears that your code has set the memory location `fNum` to the integer `233`. However, putting the address of `fNum` in a pointer to `int` and using this pointer to access it is **undefined behavior** because it contravenes “strict aliasing” rules.

Comment: OK, my english ability is not very well.

Comment: when I assign the "*pF = 233", I want to know the fNum's Value, In fact, it is a same memory, I want to know the memory hold the actual value! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

To start with, the variable `fNum` doesn't *point* to anything. It's the actual value.

And a floating point number is *not* the same as an integer. The bit-patterns in memory are *very* different for a floating point number.

Comment: when I assign the "*pF = 233", I want to know the fNum's Value, In fact, it is a same memory, I want to know the memory hold the actual value!

Comment: @imobilespace But you can't, because `*pF` is an _integer_ value, but it points to memory for a _floating point_ value. If you want `fNum` to become `233` you need `pF` to be a pointer to float, i.e. `float *`. You can read about the format for single precision floating point values [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I almost know that, the compiler think the fNum's memory address as float format all the time. Does it right?

Comment: @imobilespace No. It's not correct. Compiler know only it's a 4 or 8 byte memory . Depending on data type, it retrieve or store into memory.

Answer (score 0):

`fNum` contains [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) binary presentation of `12.3`. So when your print the content of the `fNum` memory as integer you will get the translation this binary set as decimal value